# Counting the Number of Empty Cells between Non-Empty Cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to count the number of empty cells that exist in a column between each non-empty cell but haven't been able to work out how.

Using this, I'm also trying to find the largest "empty distances" and locate the cell in the center of these distances.

The sheet I'm working with lists a set of marker colors and denotes the ones that are owned out of the full set of colors. I'm trying to find the largest ranges of missing colors and then find the colors in the middle of those ranges in order to find a handful of markers that would best help to fill out the spectrum.

**Columns 1-6 are information- Column 7 marks whether the color is owned:**

[image: Columns 1-6 are information- Column 7 marks whether the color is owned]

Answer (score 0):

I may have an answer that helps you.

I could only get it to work using a helper column, but someone may know how to eliminate that requirement.

The helper column creates an array, basically listing the row numbers of the rows that have an "x" in your column B.

The main formula then measures the gap between each of these listed row numbers.  It also checks the gap before the first "x", and after the last "x". Note that I have the data starting on row 2, which complicates the formula, but makes the sample sheet clearer - this can easily be changed to row 1 if you prefer.

```
={F2-1;
  query(ArrayFormula(if(isnumber(F3:F),F3:F-F2:F-1,"")),
    "select Col1 where Col1 > 0",0);
  counta(A2:A)-indirect("F"&COUNTA(F$2:F))}
```

[image: Counting the number of empty cell gaps in a column]

See a sample sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19QUFGRqTT6BqOsBrEBpTIxQCeNdRa5mzXhxQpCZ8sV4/edit?usp=sharing

Then I used a second formula to calculate the max gap between "x"s, (or before the first or after the last x).

Note that calculating the midpoint of the gaps, and doing a lookup of the corresponding mid-point colour, is something that can be added to this answer, if you share a sample copy of your sheet and share it for editing.

Let me know if this helps.  I'll add more explanation to describe what the formula is doing tomorrow.

And I'll provide a second tab with the formulas adjusted to work with data beginning on row 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the lengths of the gaps using Frequency:

```
=ArrayFormula(frequency(if((B1:B20<>"X")*(A1:A20<>""),row(B1:B20)),if((B1:B20="X")*(A1:A20<>""),row(B1:B20))))
```

[image]

but finding the centres of the gaps and allowing for equal-sized gaps is more difficult.

This should find the position of the "X" at the end of the longest gap:

```
=ArrayFormula(
sum(frequency(if((B1:B20<>"X")*(A1:A20<>""),row(B1:B20)),
if((B1:B20="X")*(A1:A20<>""),row(B1:B20)))*(sequence(countif(B1:B20,"X")+1,1)<=
match(max(frequency(if((B1:B20<>"X")*(A1:A20<>""),row(B1:B20)),
if((B1:B20="X")*(A1:A20<>""),row(B1:B20)))),frequency(if((B1:B20<>"X")*(A1:A20<>""),row(B1:B20)),
if((B1:B20="X")*(A1:A20<>""),row(B1:B20))),0)))+
countif(sequence(countif(B1:B20,"X")+1,1),"<="&
match(max(frequency(if((B1:B20<>"X")*(A1:A20<>""),row(B1:B20)),
if((B1:B20="X")*(A1:A20<>""),row(B1:B20)))),frequency(if((B1:B20<>"X")*(A1:A20<>""),row(B1:B20)),
if((B1:B20="X")*(A1:A20<>""),row(B1:B20))),0))
)
```

[image]

and then it should just be a case of working backwards from there to the centre of the longest gap. However the formula needs further refinement to deal with the cases

(1) Where the longest gap is after the last "X"

(2) Where there is a tie for the longest gap

(3) Where there is a need to list the longest, second longest, third longest gap etc.